# What does flower removal plots mean?

Tags: meaning, articles, definite-article

I was reading ["The impact of an alien plant on a native plant-pollinator network: an experimental approach"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17542933) and it talks about *flower removal plots* what does that mean?

> Visitation and pollen transport networks were constructed to compare replicated I. glandulifera invaded and I. glandulifera removal plots.

Comment: invasive species [of plant]; invaded refers to a plant that has invaded some area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, it's a flowerbed where some of the flowers were cut off the plants. It's explained later in the paper:

> As pollinators feed on floral resources, only the flowers of *I. glandulifera* were removed from the experimental plots (vs. the entire plant); in this way the effects of direct competition for other resources (e.g. water, light and nutrients) between *I. glandulifera* and other plant species were kept constant between control and experimental plots. The experimental plot in each pair was subjected to an *I. glandulifera* flower removal treatment, which was applied every 10–14 days throughout the experiment, this being done by hand using scissors.

In contrast:

> The control plots, henceforth referred as invaded plots, were left untreated.

Comment: So flower removal means they cut the flower ? from where? root or just the paddles? and what is invaded mean?

Comment: Laurel, a plot is bigger than a bed. :)